# why i am getting error in deployment server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am using mvc 3 and EF 4.1. In local works fine.

But in **deployment server**

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

Comment: Check that the bin directory on your deployment server contains EntityFramework.dll - could be that you referenced it but did not copy it local so it is missing.  Also, maybe the DLL got corrupted when you transferred it?  Try copying again perhaps.  Also make sure the .net version of your deployed web application is the same as your test version.